# Convert 64bit data to signed long value

Tags: java, binary, byte, bit

I have something like this:

```
byte[0] = 0001 0100 0011 0100  (dec value: 5172)  
byte[1] = 0000 0000 0111 1100  (dec value: 124)  
byte[2] = 0000 0000 0000 0000  (dec value: 0)  
byte[3] = 0000 0000 0000 0000  (dec value: 0)
```

I would like to combine them and make one long value in Java. How to do that?

Can it be converted on this way?

result = 0 +  (0 x 2^16) + (0 x 2^16) + (124 x 2^32) + (5127 x 2^48)

ie.

result = byte[3] + (byte[2] x 2^16) + (byte[1] x 2^32) + (byte[0] x 2^48)

Edit: Let me try to explain better. When I open tool ModScan32 and connect to my device I see some registers. In this tool there are different kind of options how to show data. One of them are to represent them as binary or decimal. When I choose binary or decimal I get values as they are in my example above. When I read this data with my software I get exactly the same (converted values) in the decimal. Now my question is if it is necessary to hold data in 4 16 bit registers and i know their decimal values what is the proper way to combine those values from registers and get real value?

Comment: I'm not really getting how your values are stored, but if you know decimal values, why not just write them? Otherwise consider built-int Long.parseLong methods

Comment: The values when I read them from device I get decimal values, just as in example above, each value in device is stored in 4 16bit registers so I need to convert those values from registers to long value. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Your bytes are 16 bits?? Please check. There’s no such thing as storing the value 5172 in a variable of type `byte`.

Comment: Other than that, did you try your own idea? Did it work?

Comment: I haven't worked with stuff like that, but again - search through Long.parseLong, it takes radix as parameter, which is just what you might need, after parsing each array value you will be able to work with them as with numbers

Comment: It’s difficult to suggest anything without knowing how you’re storing your values.  Consider adding some actual code, so we at least know the type of your array.  As Ole V.V. pointed out, it’s impossible for `byte[0]` to hold a 16-bit value, which makes it unclear whether your array really is of type `byte[]`.

Comment: Let me try to explain better. When I open tool ModScan32 and connect to my device I see some registers. In this tool there are different kind of options how to show data. One of them are to represent them as binary or decimal. When I choose binary or decimal I get values as they are in my example in first post. When I read this data with my software I get exactly the same (converted values) in the decimal. Now my question is if it is necessary to hold data in 4 16 bit registers and i know their decimal values what is the proper way to combine those values from registers and get real value?

Comment: Great that you explained better. Even better when you do that, [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42252272/edit) (this time I did it for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is basically OK. There are a few things to be aware of.

I believe the result you are after in your case is `0001010000110100000000000111110000000000000000000000000000000000`.

Here’s an attempt that does not work:

```
    int[] registers = { 5172, 124, 0, 0 };
    long result = registers[0] << 48 | registers[1] << 32 | registers[2] << 16 | registers[3];
    System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(result));
```

`<< 48` means shift 48 bits to the left, that should be good enough, right? `|` is a bitwise logical or, it fills the 1 bits from either operand into the same bit posistion of the result. You could use `+` instead if you preferred.

This prints:

```
10100001101000000000001111100
```

We only have the first 32 bits of the result, that’s not good enough. When trying to read it, note that `Long.toBinaryString()` does not include leading zeroes. Just imagine 3 zeroes in front of the number.

But what went worng? Where did the last 32 bits go? Even when they were all zeroes. The problem is that we are doing the calculation in `int`s, they are 32 bits, not 64. EDIT: My previous explanation was not entirely correct on this point. The truth is: When doing `<<` on an `int`, only the last 5 bits of the right operand are considered, so since 48 is 110000 in binary, only 10000 is used, so the shift is the same as `<< 16`. Similarly `<< 32` is the same as `<< 0`, no shift at all. So `registers[0]` and `[1]` have ended up in the wrong bit posistion. The solution is easy when you know it: we need to convert to `long` *before* doing the calculation. Now the last *6*  bits of the right operand are used, so 48 and 32 are understood as 48 and 32:

```
    long result = ((long) registers[0]) << 48 | ((long) registers[1]) << 32 | registers[2] << 16 | registers[3];
```

This time we get

```
1010000110100000000000111110000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Again, imagine 3 zero bits in front and all is as expected.

There is one more thing. Say you got a negative value from a register, for example:

```
    int[] registers = { 5172, -124, 0, 0 };
```

The calculation that just worked now gives us

1111111111111111111111111000010000000000000000000000000000000000

This time there are 64 bits printed, so it’s easy to see there are too many 1s in the beginning. They come from the `int` representation of -124. The solution is to mask them out:

```
    int[] registers = { 5172, -124, 0, 0 };
    long result = ((long) registers[0] & 0xFFFF) << 48
            | ((long) registers[1] & 0xFFFF) << 32 
            | (registers[2] & 0xFFFF) << 16 
            | (registers[3] & 0xFFFF);
    System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(result));
```

`0xFFFF` is 16 1 bits, and `&` is the bitwise logical ‘and’, giving a 1 bit in the result only in positions where both operands have a 1 bit. Now -124 gets masked to `1111111110000100` so the result is the expected:

```
1010000110100111111111000010000000000000000000000000000000000
```

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks on your extensive explanation. It really helped for better understanding.

Comment: Glad you liked it. If you want the precise truth, please note my correction of how `<< 48` works.